# SAS: Compare observations to other observations within BY-group

Tags: sas

EDIT: sharing for others in the future: https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings20/4778-2020.pdf

I am trying to flag observations with certain parameters that fall within a date range of other observations. I am using SAS EG. The data is at the event level and I want to group this by patient IDs (e.g., paid claims from same patient within 7 days of ANY of their claims). I am hoping to take a row, compare it to all other rows within the BY-group, and move on to the next row.

It's a large dataset (260M obs) so a SQL self-join takes way too long. I am trying to figure out if there's a better way to do this in a DATA step. I've also explored the DOW function (do *N* =1 by 1 until (last.VARIABLE)) but this seems better suited for aggregating data at the BY-group level, rather than processing and comparing individual rows. Below is an example of the data. This solution would need to flag rx_id=42 as occurring within 7 days of a rejected claim, but I don't want to be limited to consecutive rows.

| rx_id | patient_id | event_date | claim_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 6762202910 | 12/11/2020 | Paid |
| 33 | 6762202910 | 12/29/2020 | Paid |
| 34 | 6762202910 | 01/28/2021 | Paid |
| 41 | 6762205899 | 02/13/2021 | Rejected |
| 42 | 6762202910 | 02/20/2021 | Paid |

Answer (score 0):

From your brief description of the requirement (the last sentence) you appear to just need to remember when the last rejection was.

```
data want;
   set have;
   by patient_id event_date;
   if first.patient_id then last_reject=.;
   retain last_reject;
   format last_reject yymmdd10.;
   if claim_type='Rejected' then last_reject=event_date;
   if claim_type='Paid' then flag = (event_date - 7) < last_reject ;
run;
```

But I suspect that your real problem is more complex as you probably are interested in rejections that are related to the paid claim.

Comment: Remebering the last rejection might actually be enough. I also want it for paid claims but I can always just create a crosswalk with rx_id. Let me play around with this. Thanks!

Comment: This works for rejected claims, any ideas on how to modify this for paid claims as well? (Paid claims subsequent to the original paid comparator)

Comment: If the data is a mix of different "comparator groups" then you might need to use a HASH() object to store the most recent paid/rejected claim for the group.  If the group ids are simple small integers (or can be mapped to such) then you can use an array instead of a HASH().

Comment: I've never used hashes but I will take a look.

Comment: Sharing for others in the future: https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings20/4778-2020.pdf